# Resampling a frequency column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking at the panda resample function, and it seems to only work for daily and above range. But, I want to resample a 64 Hz data into 8 Hz. The file is 170 MB, so I can't attach it here, but the data has 2 arrays, one for time, and the other for the corresponding value. Is it possible to resample it using by averaging it? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Frequency is the inverse of time period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency). Essentially, you want to

1. convert frequency to time period

   ```
   df['T'] = 1 / df['f']
   ```
2. `resample` every `0.125s` (or `1/8`). Look at the [`df.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) docs for help.

Comment: I thought about that, but doesn't the resample function only accept strings?

Comment: @alexanderson If you have any trouble with the implementation, feel free to open a new question. Provide some sample data and the code that doesn't work for you, and you'll get the help you need. All the best :-)